# Where to install local Java libraries by default?

Tags: java, installation, java-native-interface, shared-libraries, autotools

I'm integrating JNI bindings with a C++ library.

The library follows the usual conventions: the installation root is `/usr/local` by default and can be modified with the `--prefix` argument to `./configure`; the `.a` or `.so` files go in `${prefix}/lib`; etc.

The JNI binding produces two new libraries, `libfoojni.so` (the native part) and `libfoo.jar` (the Java part).

Under this scheme, what is conventional place to put these files (e.g. `${prefix}/java`)?

Is it preferable to allow the user to supply a separate Java root directory (e.g., `/usr/share/java`)?

Should `libfoojni.so` go in `${prefix}/lib` or in some Java-specific sub-directory?

Answer (score 1):

When I've done JNI in the past on Linux, I've bundled the .so files with the application in a specific directory for JNI libraries. Then add this to the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable for the JVM instance running the application.

So I would say that there isn't really a convention on this (besides the Linux lib directories for system wide stuff).

Hope that helps.